# Sorting an array in a specific way in the c language

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I've been trying to sort an array of 26 randomized integer inputs in such a way that you first sort the odd integers and then you sort the even integers in an ascending order. What I've tried so far is using the selection sort algorithm and applying an if statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int arr[26], i, min, j, p;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%2d ", i);
    }
    puts("");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%2d ", arr[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
            min = i;
            for (j = i + 1; j < 25; j++) {
                if (arr[j] < arr[min]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            p = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = arr[i];
        } else {
            min = i;
            for (j = i + 1; j < 25; j++) {
                if (arr[j] < arr[min]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            p = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    puts("");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%2d ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That doesn't seem to be the correct way of doing it and I am a bit lost, since I'm a beginner. Could anyone provide any tips? Oh and apologies if my code looks like trash. Thank you for your answers

Comment: I suggest you first partition the array, putting the odd number at one end of the array and the even at the other. Then find out where the split is, and sort them using standard `qsort` as two different arrays.

Comment: The comparator function for `qsort` can be easily arranged that first it tests the "evenness" of the two items, and if the same, their value. Only one `qsort` is needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you a lot for your help. I'll give it a go using the qsort function to test it out

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I doubt that would be more efficient than sorting them in place directly. You'd iterate over the same data over and over. I posted an example as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is using a comparision function that says

- Odd numbers are smaller than even numbers
- If odd/evenness is same, compare the numbers

Also

- Your code to swap elements is wrong. `p` should be assigned instead of `arr[i]` in the third step.
- Your loops to search the minimum element are wrong because they are omitting the last element from the searching.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int cmp(int a, int b)
{
    if (a % 2 != 0 && b % 2 == 0) return -1;
    if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 != 0) return 1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[26],i,min,j,p;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        printf("%2d ", i);
    }
    puts("");
    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        printf("%2d ", arr[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        min = i;
        for(j = i+1;j<26;j++){
            if(cmp(arr[j],arr[min])<0){
                min = j;
            }
        }
        p = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[min];
        arr[min] = p;
    }

    puts("");
    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
        printf("%2d ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And... [a `qsort` alternative](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7b103eb88aa0c24) also works.

Comment: Thank you a lot. While I have some troubles understanding how exactly that function works, I think that with some time and practice I'll get it. Again appreciated a lot

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to do this in classic C is to use the [`qsort`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function and then provide a callback function specifying how to sort.

An ascending sort callback function to `qsort` could look like this:

```
int ascending (const void* o1, const void* o2)
{
  int a = *(const int*)o1;
  int b = *(const int*)o2;
  return a<b ? -1 : (a>b) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You can then write a more specialized comparison function like this:

```
int odd_then_even (const void* o1, const void* o2)
{
  int a = *(const int*)o1;
  int b = *(const int*)o2;
  
  if((a^b)&1)            // one is odd and one is even
    return a&1 ? -1 : 1; // if a is the odd return -1, otherwise return 1
  else                   // both odd or both even
    return ascending(o1, o2);
}
```

Full example using 10 unique items:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ascending (const void* o1, const void* o2)
{
  int a = *(const int*)o1;
  int b = *(const int*)o2;
  return a<b ? -1 : (a>b) ? 1 : 0;
}

int odd_then_even (const void* o1, const void* o2)
{
  int a = *(const int*)o1;
  int b = *(const int*)o2;
  
  if((a^b)&1)            // one is odd and one is even
    return a&1 ? -1 : 1; // if a is the odd return -1, otherwise return 1
  else                   // both odd or both even
    return ascending(o1, o2);
}

void print_array (int array[10]);

int main (void)
{
  int array[10] = { 7,3,2,1,5,4,9,8,0,6 };
   
  qsort(array, 10, sizeof *array, ascending);
  print_array(array);

  qsort(array, 10, sizeof *array, odd_then_even);
  print_array(array);
}

void print_array (int array[10])
{
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  puts("");
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 3 5 7 9 0 2 4 6 8
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ascending` return `0` if `a == b`? As coded, it seems to violate the constraint on the comparison function: *The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to a comparison function pointed to by `compar`, which is called with two arguments that point to the objects being compared. The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.* I wonder if this could break `qsort()` with a carefully chosen dataset.

Comment: @chqrlie doesn't really matter since qsort puts them in an unspecified order in case they are equal. Not to be confused with `bsearch`.

Comment: It should not matter, but can you prove it? The stability argument seems only partially relevant.

Comment: 7.22.5.2 "If two elements compare as equal, their order in the resulting sorted array is unspecified." Also, these functions pretends that no equal objects were found. I know of no sorting algorithm that somehow requires items to compare equal. `qsort` will likely either be implemented as quick sort or merge sort.

Comment: Yes, `qsort()` is not necessarily stable, but your function can return inconsistent results such as both `a>b` and `b>a` for `a==b` which may have side effects on a non-conventional implementation of `qsort()`. The comparison function should be self consistent and transitive.

Comment: @chqrlie I doubt it, but it might be an interesting question to ask in itself. I would expect it to work just like C++ library container classes, where overloaded < operators called by setting `std::less` etc return true or false. And std::sort doesn't explode when there are duplicates in the data.

Comment: Let me be more explicit: in order to find a value less or equal to the pivot in the second half of the array, it is possible to have a loop that just `while (a[i] > a[j]) j--;` assuming that the test will fail for `i == j` since comparing an element to itself is specified as returning 0. Your comparison function would cause this loop to run beyond the boundary if all values are greater or equal... the C++ sorting algorithm only relies on the value of `a<b`, and might exhibit the same problem if `a<a` is true.

Comment: I don't really see why a sort function would do something like that. Comparing an object against itself isn't something any of the efficient sort algorithms would do, as far as I can remember. Sure, we can always assume that `qsort` was implemented in horrible ways, but then that kind of defeats the purpose of using a library function in the first place rather than rolling out your own hardcoded bubble sort or something...

Comment: Corrected the `ascending` function after separate discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65581178/can-the-qsort-comparison-function-always-return-a-non-zero-value

Comment: Pedantic: `if((a^b)&1)` is an OK test for 2's complement `int`, yet fails for that junkyard dinosaur with 1s' complement.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Well, the day you find such a computer, you can also use `(a%2) ^ (b%2)`. I just tend to avoid division out of old habit since it tends to result in poor machine code, at least historically.