# Can the qsort comparison function always return a non-zero value?

Tags: c, sorting, language-lawyer, qsort

An ascending sort callback function for `qsort` and `bsearch` on an array of `int` could look like this:

```
int ascending(const void *o1, const void *o2) {
    int a = *(const int *)o1;
    int b = *(const int *)o2;
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Yet this function seems to violate the constraint on the `compar` function as specified in the C Standard:

> **7.22.5.2 The `qsort` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
>            int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
> ```
>
> **Description**
> The `qsort` function sorts an array of `nmemb` objects, the initial element of which is pointed to by `base`. The size of each object is specified by `size`.
>
> The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to a comparison function pointed to by `compar`, which is called with two arguments that point to the objects being compared. The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
>
> If two elements compare as equal, their order in the resulting sorted array is unspecified.

Is this comparison function OK or can it cause undefined behavior?

Comment: This comparison function is just not considering any two elements as equal. I don't see why anything is violated.

Comment: If there are no two elements equal, then yes.

Comment: bsearch is another story than qsort - you can assume that bsearch will check for equivalence.

Comment: Certainly the intent of a comparison function is that an object must be equal to itself, and therefore a properly designed comparison function will return equal (zero) if `o1` and `o2` point to the same object. Further, if `o1` and `o2` point to two objects with the same bytes, we would expect it to return equal. A better question might be that, given a broken comparison function like this, is there any reasonable sort algorithm that fails when using it?

Comment: Oh and btw, this ought to be a legit use-case I think? `int dont_sort (const void *o1, const void *o2) { return -1; }`

Comment: I know this is tagged `language-lawyer`, and hence the answer is '_it doesn't matter_'... but I have the question of why not just check for equality and return `0`? i.e. a second better question might be: is there any real-world need _not_ to `return 0` for equal elements? (other than excessive brevity)

Comment: What happens when `a == b`? Your function will return `1`, indicating to `qsort` that `a` is *greater than* `b`. Won't that (potentially) make the sort operation unending?

Comment: @chqrlie: Done, thanks. I still think the (now deleted) question is interesting, but it needs better framing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I agree. I suspect some classic implementations of `qsort` would fail with an appropriate dataset. Vlad exhibited a counter example for `bsearch`, but it is rather obvious that `bsearch` should fail if the comparison function never returns `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C 2018 7.22.5 4 says:

> When the same objects (consisting of size bytes, irrespective of their current positions in the array) are passed more than once to the comparison function, the results shall be consistent with one another. That is, for `qsort` they shall define a total ordering on the array, and for `bsearch` the same object shall always compare the same way with the key.

A [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) requires that *a* = *a*. (To see this from the definition in the Wikipedia page: Connexity says, for any *a* and *b*, *a* ≤ *b* or *b* ≤ *a*. Substituting *a* for *b* gives *a* ≤ *a* or *a* ≤ *a*. So *a* ≤ *a*. Then the condition of antisymmetry is satisfied: We have *a* ≤ *a* and *a* ≤ *a*, so *a* = *a*.)

Comment: I think this settles it, I wasn't aware of this paragraph. So it is formally UB.

Comment: Also, turns out this part was apparently added in C99, it wasn't there in C90.

Answer (score 2):

Using such a function at least with `bsearch` can result in undefined behavior.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ascending(const void *o1, const void *o2) {
    int a = *(const int *)o1;
    int b = *(const int *)o2;
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}

int ascending1(const void *o1, const void *o2) {
    int a = *(const int *)o1;
    int b = *(const int *)o2;

    return ( b < a ) - ( a < b );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    qsort( a, N, sizeof( int ), ascending );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    int key = 1;

    int *p = bsearch( &key, a, N, sizeof( int ), ascending );
    
    if ( p ) printf("*p = %d, p - a = %zu\n", *p, ( size_t )( p - a ) );
    else puts( "Oops!" );

    p = bsearch( &key, a, N, sizeof( int ), ascending1 );
    
    if ( p ) printf("*p = %d, p - a = %zu\n", *p, ( size_t )( p - a ) );
    else puts( "Oops!" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 0 1 1 2 2 
Oops!
*p = 1, p - a = 3
```

`qsort` can work depending on its internal implementation.

But in any case you have undefined behavior because the comparison function does not satisfy the requirements.